# Firebase reading returns null

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I'm trying to get user information from Firebase database, but it always returns null. Here is my code for reading current user information from database

```
func workWithDataBase(){
    let email = "test@gmail.com"
    let password = "test23"


    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        } else {
            print("SIGNED IN\n")

            let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
            }) {
                (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }   
        }
    }) 
}
```

and here is the output and the screenshot of Firebase database
[image]

[image]

My question is if the fields for email and name are not empty why "observeSingleEvent" method returns null? How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi! First suggestion: you have selected the child "users" instead of "user".

Comment: Thank you it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        }) {(error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```